# Delete element from List in Scheme

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I have  list in this form

```
( (1 3) (2 2) (3 1) (4 5) (5 1)))
```

and I want to delete an item let's say `(3 1)`

So the result will be

```
( (1 3) (2 2) (4 5) (5 1)))
```

I have written something like this and I do not know why it is not running correctly.

```
(define (deleteItem list item)
  (cond
    ((equal? item (car  list)) (cdr list))
    (cons (car  list)(deleteItem(cdr list) item))))
```

Comment: Be aware that Racket's built-in `remove` (which some of the answers refer to) only removes the _first_ occurrence of the item.  If you wanted to remove _all_ of them, you'd need `remove*`. Your current code is closer to `remove` than `remove*`, but it's not clear whether you wanted to remove just the first occurrence, or all of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built-in function for this, it's called [`remove`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%29%29):

```
(define lst
  '((1 3) (2 2) (3 1) (4 5) (5 1)))

(remove '(3 1) lst)
=> '((1 3) (2 2) (4 5) (5 1))
```

… But I guess you need to implement it from scratch. Some suggestions for your code:

- You should not use `list` as a parameter name, that'll clash with a built-in function. Let's call it `lst` instead
- You're missing the base case necessary form most list procedures: what happens if the list is empty?
- You're also missing the `else` part in the last condition

With all the above fixes in place, the procedure will work:

```
(define (deleteItem lst item)
  (cond ((null? lst)
         '())
        ((equal? item (car lst))
         (cdr lst))
        (else
         (cons (car lst) 
               (deleteItem (cdr lst) item)))))

(deleteItem lst '(3 1))
=> '((1 3) (2 2) (4 5) (5 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

The procedure already exists:

```
(remove '(3 1) '((1 3) (2 2) (3 1) (4 5) (5 1))))
```

Otherwise your procedure should look like this:

```
(define (deleteItem item list) 
  (cond 
    ((empty? list) '())
    ((equal? item (car list)) (cdr list))
    (else (cons (car list) (deleteItem item (cdr list))))))
```

You missed:

- the base case, (empty? list)
- the "else" in the final clause

and you shouldn't use *list* as a variable name because it shadows the build-in procedure `list` (but it will work).

Answer (score 0):

1) if consider the input list may be a simple list, or you just want to delete the item in the top-level of a nested list
for example:

```
delete 2 from (1 2 3 4) will return (1 2 3)
delete 2 from (1 2 3 (2 3) 3 2 4) will return (1 3 (2 3) 3 4)
```

as we can see the 2nd example above, it just delete the item in the top-level of the nested list, within the inner list, we doesn't change it.

this code should be:

```
(define (deleteitem list1 item) 
( cond
    ((null? list1) ’())
    ((equal? (car list1) item) (deleteItem (cdr list1) item)) 
    (else (cons (car list1) (deleteitem (cdr list1) item)))
))
```

2) if consider the input list may be a nested list

for example:

```
input list: (1 2 3 (3 2 (2 4 (2 5 6) 2 5 6) 2 4) 2 3 (2 3 4))
```

and delete the element 2 in the input list

```
the output list should be: (1 3 (3 (3 (5 6) 5 6) 4) 3 (3 4))
```

and the code should be:

```
(define (delete2 list1 item) 
    ( cond
    ((null? list1) '())
    ((pair? (car list1)) (con (delete2 (car list1) item) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)))
    ((equal? (car list1) item) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)) 
    (else (cons (car list1) (delete2 (cdr list1) item)))
))
```