# How do I filter out the first occurrence from a list in Racket using plai-typed?

Tags: functional-programming, racket

In Racket using plai-typed, I am trying to find an element in a list and remove the first one it finds. It will then return the list with the first element it sees removed.
Here is an example:

'(1 2 3 2 5) 
Filter out the first 2 and you should get:
'(1 3 2 5)

This is what I am currently doing, but it returns: '(1 3 5)
(filter (lambda (x) (not (equal? x 2))) '(1 2 3 2 5))

So what I am currently doing removes all the occurrences when I just want to remove the first one.

Comment: You can use the built-in [remove](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html?q=remove#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._remove%29%29) for this, i.e. `(remove 2 (list 1 2 3 2 4))` ==> `'(1 3 2 4)`. Otherwise, see [how to delete element from list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913606/delete-element-from-list-in-scheme).

Comment: How is this a duplicate when plai-typed does not have a remove function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[edit]If you did not want to use that built in function you can do

```
(define (remove-1st-helper l n)
 (cond [(empty? l) empty]
       [(= 1 n) l]
       [(= 2 (first l)) (remove-1st-helper (rest l)(add1 n))]
       [else (cons (first l) (remove-1st-helper (rest l) n))]))

(define (remove-1st-occurence l)
   (if (empty? l) empty (remove-1st-helper l 0)))
```

Comment: This is not what OP is asking, please test your answers before posting incorrect solutions.

Comment: sorry about that oscar, i misread what he had asked about.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know Racket, but maybe you can define it as a piece-wise function like this:

```hs
-- Define myFilter of an empty list to be empty
myFilter [] = []

-- Decomposes list into first element and rest of list
myFilter (x:xs) 
    -- Ignore `x` but include the rest of the list
    | x == 2 = xs 
    -- Include x and apply myFilter on xs
    | otherwise = x:(myFilter xs)
```

(Haskell code).